# Can I bake Shape Keys to an animation?

Tags: animation, keyframes, shape-keys

I have a very simple animation of a string of vertices in my scene that I have animated with shape keys. Is there a way to bake the shape key animation to my mesh so I can go and mess with the mesh in different ways? *(I've already tried Object>Animation>Bake Action and it doesn't work)*

Comment: I dont think there is such way ... Bake action is for Object, Shape Keys  stores vertex location only. YOu cant animate vertex via NLA ... I can imagine only Hook vertex to empty a nd animate empty. What kind of messing are you planning? You can add another empty on top of existing ... anyway since Shape keys does anim in linear way - straight motion from loc to loc in is much flexible to work with bones ...